# Can Spark map function assign dynamic variable?

Tags: apache-spark, map-function

I know map function can do like

```
val a=5
map(data=>data+5)
```

Is that possible variable a can be dynamic?

For example, the value of variable a is between 1 to 5 so a=1,2,3,4,5.
When I call map function, it can distributed execute like

```
data + 1
data + 2
data + 3
data + 4
data + 5
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question, could you specify better what you are trying to do?

Comment: can you look at this question @Rohan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150147/master-must-start-with-yarn-spark

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it doesn't make sense from a Spark perspective. What you're asking for makes sense in a non-distributed, sequential processing environment (where each datum can be deterministically applied a different function). However, Spark applies transformations across distributed datasets and the functions applied by these transformations are identical.

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use some inherent qualities of the input in transforming your data. This way, even if your transformation function is identical, the arguments provided to it will allow it do behave like (what you described as) a "dynamic variable". In your example, the [`zipWithIndex()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1235) function can suffice. Though it is important to note that if ordering is not guaranteed, the indexes are subject to change on each run of the transformation.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,1,1,1,1,1))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> val newRDD = rdd.zipWithIndex().map { case (elem, idx) => elem + idx }
...
scala> newRDD.take(6)
...
res0: Array[Long] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```