# Master must start with yarn,spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt

I am getting this error when is want to run SparkPi example.

```
   beyhan@beyhan:~/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4$ /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --master ego-client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.jar
        Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
        Error: Master must start with yarn, spark, mesos, or local
        Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
        Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

Also i already start my master via another terminal

```
>./sbin/start-master.sh 
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../logs/spark-beyhan-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-beyhan.out
```

Any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download and extract Spark:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget -c http://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.2.0/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz
$ cd /tmp
$ tar zxf ~/Downloads/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz
$ cd spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/
```

Start master:

```
$ sbin/start-master.sh
```

Find master's URL from logs in the file that above command printed. Lets assume that master is: `spark://ego-server:7077`

In this case, you can also find your master url by visiting this URL: http://localhost:8080/

Start one slave, and connect it to master:

```
$ sbin/start-slave.sh --master spark://ego-server:7077
```

Another way to ensure that master up and running start a shell bound to that master:

```
$ bin/spark-submit --master "spark://ego-server:7077"
```

If you get a spark shell, then everything seems fine.

Now execute your job:

```
$ find . -name "spark-example*jar"
./lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar

$ bin/spark-submit --master "spark://ego-server:7077" --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi ./lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

Comment: Thanks your reply.I did it,i can run jar file but i can't create a jar file with using sbt.How can i do?also  could you say it ? :)

Comment: @BeyhanGül thats great! Could you describe your sbt issue in a separate StackOverflow question ?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting

> Error: Master must start with yarn, spark, mesos, or local

Means that `--master ego-client` is not recognized by spark.

Use

```
--master local
```

for a local execution of spark or

```
--master spark://your-spark-master-ip:7077
```

Comment: i tried /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --master local   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.jar this but getting another error               Warning: Local jar /home/beyhan/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.jar does not exist, skipping.

Comment: Are you sure that there's spark-examples-1.jar in that folder? it looks like there isn't.

Comment: yes i don't have any jar file. how can i create jar file from my scala codes ?

Comment: Having a build.sbt file in your project you can use the tool sbt with 'sbt package' command

Comment: yes i know that but i have a error.can you look at this my question also =? about build.sbt      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143665/spark-sbt-compile-error-librarydependencies